# Access profile pictures using Facebook's Graph API v2.3 without user login

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Direct access to profile pictures via the Facebook graph API has recently stopped working and appears deprecated.  Apparently, this now requires an access token (which requires the user to login to FB first)...

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/picture?redirect=false&type=large
```

I'm developing a web application in JavaScript, unrelated to Facebook.  I would like to offer users the option to use their FB profile picture for posts.  They provide their numeric user-id which I save on our server.  Until recently, my client app could use the numeric user-id in the above URL to produce a JSON response with a link to the user's profile picture.

Is there an alternative approach to getting a user's profile picture without first requiring the user to login to FB to get a client-side access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *They (the users) provide their numeric user-id* means that you're using Facebook Login, and they at least gave their `public_profile` permission to your app, you can just add the App Access Token to the request and it should work.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/picture?redirect=false&type=large&access_token={app_access_token}
```

If you don't use Facebook Login, I see no chance to be honest.

Comment: I explain to the users how to get their numeric user-id from their FB page.  So, I guess you are right in that they do login to FB, but not as part of my application.  My app is not a "Facebook App" and I do not have any plans to allow login via FB at this time.

Comment: It would be somewhat expensive, but I believe I can register my app with FB to get one of the token types.  Then I could use the token to get profile picture urls to send back to my client.  It would be a hit to UX for sure, but I think it's at least possible.  In fact, I use email for usernames and might be able to get profile pictures if they use the same email for FB.  This would be best case as the user would not have to provide any numeric user-ids and such.

Comment: This is not possible without Login. Your App can  surely live outside of Facebook and anyway use the Facebook Login mechanisms. Thousands of websites are using this.

Comment: I bit the bullet and integrated FB login support.  I did take considerably longer than expected, but did provide access to profile pictures and potentially more as my app evolves.